# tensowflow keras - model.predict giving all same outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

1. model. predict giving all same outputs
2. Getting low validation
   and test accuracy < 60 %

I tried changing the last hidden layer to softmax but it still didn't solve this issue. Any feedback would be appreciated. I also tried playing with the hyperparameters but I still couldn't find any fix.

````
 raw_cvs_data = np.loadtxt('data_to_train.csv',delimiter=',')
 raw_cvs_data_to_compute = np.loadtxt('data_to_compute.csv',delimiter=',')

 unscaled_inputs_all = raw_cvs_data[:,1:]
 targets_all = raw_cvs_data[:,0]
 inputs_to_compute = raw_cvs_data_to_compute[:]
 predicted_target=[]

 # balancing the dataset
 num_one_targets = int(np.sum(targets_all)) # count how many targets are 1
 zero_targets_counter = 0 # counter for target 0

 indices_to_remove = [] # remove extra input/target pairs for balance 

 # count the number of targets 0, when get same amount of target 1 and 0, make entries where target is zero
 for i in range(targets_all.shape[0]):
         if targets_all[i] == 0:
             zero_targets_counter +=1
             if zero_targets_counter > num_one_targets:
                 indices_to_remove.append(i)

 unscaled_inputs_equal_priors = np.delete(unscaled_inputs_all,indices_to_remove, axis = 0)

 targets_equal_priors = np.delete(targets_all, indices_to_remove, axis = 0)
 #Shuffle the data 
 shuffled_indices = np.arange(scaled_inputs.shape[0])
 np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indices) #shuffle pairs

 shuffled_inputs = scaled_inputs[shuffled_indices]
 shuffled_targets = targets_equal_priors[shuffled_indices]
 # splitting data
 samples_count = shuffled_inputs.shape[0]

 # |training|validation|testing| 80-10-10
 train_samples_count = int(0.8 * samples_count)
 validation_samples_count = int(0.1 *samples_count)
 test_samples_count = samples_count - train_samples_count - validation_samples_count

 train_inputs = shuffled_inputs[:train_samples_count]
 train_targets = shuffled_targets[:train_samples_count]

 validation_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_samples_count:train_samples_count + validation_samples_count]
 validation_targets = shuffled_targets[train_samples_count:train_samples_count + validation_samples_count]

 test_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_samples_count + validation_samples_count:]
 test_targets = shuffled_targets[train_samples_count + validation_samples_count:]
 np.savez('training_data', inputs=train_inputs, targets=train_targets)
 np.savez('validation_data', inputs=validation_inputs, targets=validation_targets)
 np.savez('test_data', inputs=test_inputs, targets=test_targets)
 np.savez('data_to_compute', inputs=inputs_to_compute)


 #model.py-


 input_size = 22
 output_size = 2 # 0 / 1
 hidden_layer_size = 50 # width

 model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid'),tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid')])

 model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
 max_epochs = 500
 model.fit(train_inputs, 
           train_targets, 
           batch_size=1,
           epochs=max_epochs, 
           callbacks = [early_stopping],
           validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets),
           validation_steps=10,
           verbose=2
          )
 prediction = model.predict(data_to_compute)

[[0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
      [0.09466213 0.09515946]
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .]```
````

Comment: Pls confirm that you are trying to do *classification*  (and not regression); also, are your labels one-hot encoded (i.e. `[0, 1], [1, 0]`) or single digits (`0, 1` etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from this line of code:  `tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid')`.

The problem is that you are using the '`sigmoid`' activation with 2 neurons, instead of 1.

Either use `2 neurons + activation = 'softmax'` or `1 neuron + activation='sigmoid'`.

Answer (score 0):

If, as it seems, you are trying to do *classification* with one-hot encoded labels, then there are two issues with your code.

First, you are using the wrong loss; mean squared error (MSE) is used for *regression* problems, and not classification ones. Change your model compilation to use the binary cross-entropy loss, i.e.:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Second, as hinted already in the other answer, change the activation function of your last layer to `softmax`, i.e.:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')
```

which is the correct one for one-hot encoded labels.

Comment: Didn't even see the mse in classification. Great obsevation